# Split bandwidth between WiFi and LAN

Tags: windows-7, bandwidth, adsl-router

I have a `TP-LINK` ADSL2+ Modem and want to know if there is a way to split the bandwidth allocation of WiFi connections and LAN connection with the ratio that I want?
e.g. 1/4 of bandwidth for WiFi and the rest for LAN
OS: Windows 7
Model: TD-W8901G

---

Edit: According to `Abhioxic`'s suggestion I found QoS on 192.168.1.1 and it looks like below. I think I'm closer now, but what next?

[image]

Comment: What model TP-Link ? Bandwidth is split already as that's how networking works. I'm assuming you want to limit bandwidth going to either LAN/Wifi or both.

Comment: If you want to *limit* bandwidth, QoS is not the right tool. It affects only outgoing traffic, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can install a different firmware like [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com) for your modem to enable you to do something similar.

Enabling QoS using something like [this guide](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Quality_of_Service#Initial_Setup) should suffice for what you want to do.

This is a copy and paste of what the guide says for initial setup, but you should always refer to the documentation to make sure they haven't updated it since the copy and paste.

```
Log into the Web Interface 

Select the NAT/QoS tab and then the QoS sub-tab. 

Click "Enable" 

Set Port to "WAN". The term WAN here refers to the WAN connection on your router while
the term "LAN & WLAN" refers to the combination of your local ports and Wifi
connections. Selecting "WAN" will apply QoS only to traffic moving into or out of your
network, while selecting "LAN & WLAN" will apply QoS to ALL traffic passing through
the router on your network. Selecting "LAN & WLAN" will limit WLAN<->WLAN and
LAN<->WLAN transfer speeds to the lowest of the uplink/downlink speeds that you set
while also limiting the LAN & WLAN<->WAN rates, and thus will not be the preferred
solution for most people. 

Select HFSC as your packet scheduler. 

Select FQ_CODEL as your queueing discipline. 

Set your upload and download speeds. You can use a speed test like Speedtest.net to
check your actual connection speed. Some ISPs also provide their own bandwidth testing
service, which may be more reliable than the links provided. Enter no higher than 
90% of the values you measured into the proper fields. After you have everything set 
run the speed test again. If you get near 90% of your previous measurement in each
direction then things are cool. If you get results which are way off then chances
are that you have reversed these values. You must enter a value for the uplink field
but if you want you can enter 0 for the downlink field in which case no QoS will occur
in that direction though setting your downlink field to 0 isn't recommended.
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and it maybe helpful for future visitors but I searched my modem [there](http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/support/router-database) and seems it's not supported.

Comment: Oops, Misread. Sorry. Either way, you can have a look for aftermarket firmware to see if any will fit on the modem and do what you need it to do.

Answer (score -1):

There's a trick I can suggest.
Make your computers IP static, either by reservation or by DynDNS.
On ur router page ( 192.168.0.1 / 192.168.1.1 ) Search for QoS service.
If ur router supports it, u can allocate bandwidth along varous IPs connected to ur network, or do The 1/4th of bandwidth stuff. Do a little research as u havent gave much informations.
Dynamic DNS : www.dyndns.com
QoS: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quality_of_service
Edit: It's very hard to figure out the QoS setup shown above, even the support is not answering it.
However here's a link to the manual by TPLink , QoS info is given in it. Link:  http://www.tp-link.in/resources/software/2008529201864.pdf

Comment: Thanks I'll try it and what info do you need?

Comment: I just edited my post.

Comment: Ur routers model number. Something like TDW81GB ..... Although I have no experience in TP link. Add a tag of it if possible.

Comment: How exactly does DynDNS handle and manage the allocation of ip addresses?

Comment: Dynamic DNS is for those who dont have a static IP. Suppose u hv a router and a computer. Now the IP will be assigned according who connects first. Suppose ur mobile connects first, then it will get IP 192.168.0.100, while the second connection will get *.101 IP. Its a pain to check whats ur computer IP is as it keeps changing. In this case Dynamic DNS comes handy. With DynDNS or DDNS u can register a domain for your IP. Eg. A.b.c add this in ur router configuratn and whatever the IP ur computer gets it will auTy omatically be linked with ur domain. Want CS?ur permanent ip will be a.b.c:23501.